# How to detect if response from http request is null flutter

Tags: flutter, http

I'm using http package, and I want to detect null response (in case of a wrong url). I tested this example on DartPad:

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  // This example uses the Google Books API to search for books about http.
  // https://developers.google.com/books/docs/overview
  var url =
      Uri.https('www.googl', '/books/v1/volumes', {'q': '{http}'});

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
  var response ;
  try{
       response = await http.get(url);
  }
  on Exception catch (_) {
  print(response.toString().isEmpty); 
  print(response.statusCode.toString());  
  print(response.body.isNotEmpty);
  print(response.headers.isEmpty);
  }
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse =
        convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
    print('Number of books about http: $itemCount.');
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }

 
}
```

And that is what I get as output:

```
false
Uncaught Error: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'get$body' on null
```

In this case `response.toString()` is not NULL, so how can I detect if the response was null?

Answer (score 0):

You can print `response.body` in the fetch function:

```
print(response.body);
```